# In Oracle 11g parent tag value is not selected in result set if no nested tag for it in XML document

Tags: xml, oracle

I have nested xml document. But on some places there is no nesting. I try to fetch all information to insert into table. But the query is not returning parent tag value if there is no nesting(child tag). I want null value to be returned at place of child tag with parent tag value if no nesting is present. Below is the 
**code to Create data in table**

```
    create table xmldata as
with xmldoc as (
select xmlType('
    <detailedOutput>
    <entity>
        <entityLabel>Parent tag with child</entityLabel>
        <entityName>P with C</entityName>
        <entityType>P with C</entityType>
        <fact>
            <name>I am child 1</name>
        </fact>
        <fact>
            <name>I am child 2</name>
        </fact>
    </entity>
    <entity>
        <entityLabel>Parent tag with no child</entityLabel>
        <entityName>P with no C</entityName>
        <entityType>P with no C</entityType>
    </entity>
    </detailedOutput>
    ') xml from dual
)
select xml from xmldoc
```

**Code to select result:**

```
select
    extractValue (value(e), '/entity/entityLabel') as "entityLabel",
    extractValue (value(e), '/entity/entityName')  as "entityName",
    extractValue (value(e), '/entity/entityType')  as "entityType",
    extractValue (value(f), '/fact/name')          as "factName" 
from xmldata x,
    table (xmlSequence(extract(xml,      '/detailedOutput/entity'))) e,
    table (xmlSequence(extract(value(e), '/entity/fact'))) f
```

Here I am getting following result:
[result without parent tag value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wK589.jpg)

Here value for entityLabel field **Parent tag with no child** is not selected. Please help me how to pares mentioned xml document to select parent tag value with child value null if no child tag present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're doing an `INNER JOIN` on `f`, which removes all entities which don't have fact/name children. Try this instead.

```
select 
    extractValue (value(e), '/entity/entityLabel') as "entityLabel",
    extractValue (value(e), '/entity/entityName')  as "entityName",
    extractValue (value(e), '/entity/entityType')  as "entityType",
    extractValue (value(f), '/fact/name')          as "factName" 
from xmldoc x
inner join table (xmlSequence(extract(xml,      '/detailedOutput/entity'))) e 
    on 1=1
left join table (xmlSequence(extract(value(e), '/entity/fact'))) f 
    on value(e) is not null
```

I'm not sure why `f` needs a join condition to `e`, but it doesn't work right without it.

Comment: So comma-separated tables in XML are inner joins and not cross joins as regular ANSI-SQL? I had a [UNION query version](http://rextester.com/QJRW81612) in the works.

Comment: I didn't try running an explain plan, but I think the `table(xmlSequence())` is adding an implicit join condition behind the scenes. I don't think it can be a cross join, since the pseudo-tables are clearly not independent of each other.